# Command lines for moving and renaming files with new name input

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename, move

I'm trying to make a batch file with Windows command lines that will rename a file and move it to another location while only needing me to input the new name of the file. I've seen some different methods but none for this specifically all at once that actually work for me.

Here is the code I've used and gotten an error message

```
@echo off
set /p newname=New File Name: 
ren /Y C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\file.mp4 %newname%.mp4
move %newname%.mp4 C:\Users\Test\Videos
```

I've also tried this one with no luck

```
@echo off
set /p "newname=New File Name: "
move /Y file.mp4 C:\Users\Test\Videos\%newname%.mp4
```

Comment: Are you running as administrator? AFAIK editing files in the `Program Files` folder requires administrator access. I could be wrong though. What is the specific error message you are getting?

Comment: Yes I run as administrator and the error I get is 'The syntax of the command is incorrect.'

Comment: Iirc `ren` does not have a `/Y` switch, try running the first snippet without it. Also try quoting your filepath since it has spaces like `ren /Y "C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\file.mp4" "%newname%.mp4"`. The `move` command will not work unless your current directory is in that folder. Either use the fully quantified filepath or `cd` to the folder first

Comment: Thanks for the help it finally worked. Taking ```/Y``` off and putting the filepath in quotes did the trick.

Comment: @MurkN, please take the [tour] so that you know what to do after someone answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ren` does not have a `/Y` switch, try running

```
@echo off
set /p newname=New File Name: 
ren C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\file.mp4 %newname%.mp4
move %newname%.mp4 C:\Users\Test\Videos
```

Also try quoting your filepath since it has spaces like

```
ren /Y "C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\file.mp4" "%newname%.mp4"
```

The `move` command will not work unless your current directory is in that folder. Either use the fully quantified filepath or `cd` to the folder first as well

Comment: in your first example, please double quote your paths. i.e `ren "C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\file.mp4" "%newname%.mp4"` etc..